# Incompatible pointer types warning with custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView in a view controller. The table view uses a custom cell called UserFavoritesCell. When referencing this cell in code, I get the following warning:

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing UserFavoritesCell with an expression of UITableViewCell.
```

Since UserFavoritesCell is a subclass of UITableViewCell I'm not sure why I am getting this warning. Any ideas? THanks!

Header:

```
@interface UserFavoriteCell : UITableViewCell

// properties...

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation UserFavoriteCell

@synthesize lblFlow, lblHeight, lblLastUpdate, lblMainTitle, gaugeID;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

In my view controller I am getting the warning on instantiation of UserFavoriteCell as follows:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UserFavoriteCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; // warning
    GaugeViewController *gvc = [[GaugeViewController alloc] init];
    [gvc setGaugeID:[cell gaugeID]];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sgDetailFave" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: Why you using the cell and you are not using the actual data source to get gaugeID? This method will actually re-create or recall the cell from the queue just to retrieve a property that already exists in your data i guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but did you try casting the cell?

```
UserFavoriteCell *cell = (UserFavoriteCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> Since `UserFavoritesCell` is a subclass of `UITableViewCell` I'm not sure why I am getting this warning. Any ideas?

Because while every orange is a fruit, not every fruit is an orange...

`cellForRowAtIndexPath:` only knows the table contains `UITableViewCell`s (fruit). If you *know* the returned cell is a `UserFavoritesCell` (orange) then you can assert that with a cast:

```
... cell = (UserFavoritesCell *) ...
```

Without the assertion (and the compiler trusts you to get it right) the compiler can only know it has an `UITableViewCell`, hence the warning.